# Multivariable calculus along with tensors ...etc to start studying General Relativity

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus, general-relativity

I bought Spivak Calculus on Manifolds last time and I was really really disappointed... I opened the first chapters and I understood nothing of what he was saying.

But i need to understand multivariable calculus along with tensors and all that stuff to start study General relativity next semester...

Which book do you recommend me? (someone that contain everything 
    (Partial) Differentiation
    (Multiple) Integration
    Curves and Surfaces in R3
    Vector Calculus (Green's Theorem, Stokes' Theorem, Divergence Theorem)
)

THANKS

Comment: Have you studied Classical Electromagnetics yet?

Comment: @pkjag Nope.... But I will do it before relativity

Comment: Then you need to because AFAIK it offers the best practice to multivariable calculus. You should start with this http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/ then when you are done go to this http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02sc-physics-ii-electricity-and-magnetism-fall-2010/

Comment: @pkjag No I will study in the book Griffiths Introduction to electrodynamics (I already brought)  but first I need a good Multi Variable Calculus book.....

Comment: But i don't think you are ready for general relativity yet, for that you'll need a lot of background material like ODE's, PDE's, Special Relativity, Analytical Mechanics, Statistical Mechanics, Quantum Mechanics, Tensor Calculus, e.t.c see this http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html for a complete coverage, it also has many more links.

Comment: okay but I want to learn multivariable calculus what do you recommend me? @pkjag

Comment: I recommend http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/, download the course materials at the website.

Comment: I mean a textbook that goes in all the theorems and stuuf about multivariable calculus

Comment: What makes you think that the ocw MIT course doesn't offer that. Spivak's book is more about the advanced theoretical stuff and you have to have done the practical stuff before you can read that book. And as far as i know MIT's courses are solid especially the SCs and the two courses i recommended are both SCs, if this doesn't help then go to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44522/theoretical-multivariable-calculus-textbooks?rq=1 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155263/multivariable-calculus-book-reference?rq=1