# Best multivariable calculus text for physics

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question, physics

I will soon start studying electrodynamics from Griffith's *Electrodynamics*. I tried to learn the math required from the first chapter but found that I couldn't understand it very well. So are there some good textbooks for learning multivariable calculus?

Comment: Maybe tell us a little more about your math background. Did you take a multivariable calculus class and just don't remember? Or are you trying to jump right into Griffith's?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155263/multivariable-calculus-book-reference, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44522/theoretical-multivariable-calculus-textbooks, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43290/references-for-the-multivariable-calculus.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [Div, Grad, Curl, and All That: An Informal Text on Vector Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393925161) by H. M. Schey.

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but how can you possibly think that this answer the question?

Comment: @Ant it's a book recommendation...

Comment: Ahahahah that was neat! Next time post a link from the beginning :-D :-D